# 0 test cases found and completed when i run ./gradlew test

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

This is the build.gradle file and its dependencies that I have added to run the test cases.
While I try running the ./gradlew test it gives me 0 test cases completed.
I have 30 test files in my repo and have also tried adding @QuarkusTest annotation but it didn't work.
Need help with the missing dependencies.

```
    id 'java'
    id 'io.quarkus'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username MAVEN_REPO_USERNAME
            password MAVEN_REPO_PASSWORD
        }
        url REPOSITORY_URL
    }
}

// Definition source which should include.
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }

    test {
        java{
            srcDir 'src/test/java/unit'
            srcDir 'src/test/java/component'
        }
    }
}

processResources {
    from ('src/main/java')
    exclude ('**/*.java')
}

dependencies {
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson"
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.5.0'
    implementation 'com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'io.quarkus', name: 'quarkus-narayana-jta', version: '2.1.3.Final'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-mysql'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal'
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
    }
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-s3'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-sqs'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-logging-json'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'
    implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core"
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest-client'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler'
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11"
    implementation "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2"
    implementation 'org.opensearch.client:opensearch-rest-high-level-client:2.0.0'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-micrometer'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.6.1'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-health:1.10.2.Final'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'

    compile(
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.35",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.272",
            "javax.activation:activation:1.1",
            "javax.mail:mail:1.4.3",
            "commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4",
            "commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.5",
            "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1",
            "javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-bean-validation:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:2.27",
            "org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.25.1",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.9.7",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:5.8.2",
            "org.javassist:javassist:3.16.1-GA",
            "org.json:json:20230227",
            "commons-io:commons-io:2.4",
            "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1",
            "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.21",
            "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final",
            "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:3.1.0",
            "io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jersey2:3.1.0",
            "commons-modeler:commons-modeler:2.0.1",
            "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1",
            "com.google.guava:guava:18.0",
            "net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:3.0.3",
            "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.2",
            "com.googlecode.concurrent-trees:concurrent-trees:2.4.0",
            "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1",
            "commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1",
            "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.13",
            "org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.1",
            "io.searchbox:jest:5.3.3",
            "com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib:1.0.2",
            "com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1",
            "xerces:xercesImpl:2.12.2",
            "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1",
            "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0",
            "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1",
            "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.0",
            // Adding lz4 dependency here because common library doesn't expose it.
            "org.lz4:lz4-java:1.5.0",
            //This library provides extensive support for both IPv4 & Ipv6.
            //https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.seancfoley/ipaddress
            //https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.seancfoley/ipaddress/5.2.1
            "com.github.seancfoley:ipaddress:5.2.1",
            "org.opensearch.client:opensearch-rest-high-level-client:2.5.0",
            "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.17.1",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.31",
            "com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:1.12.288",
            "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:1.15",
            "org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:2.7",
            "net.minidev:json-smart:2.4.8",
            "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:1.15",
            "org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.3.1",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.0-rc1",
            "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1",
            "org.springframework:spring-expression:5.3.23",
            "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4",
            "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:2.13.4",
            "org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-core:6.2.0.Final",
            "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0.1",
            "io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.82.Final",
            "io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.82.Final",
            "org.apache.xmlgraphics:fop:2.8",
            "org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:1.15"
    )
    compile ("org.docx4j:docx4j:3.3.1") {
        exclude group: 'xalan', module:'xalan'
    }
    compile ("org.docx4j:docx4j-export-fo:3.3.1") {
        exclude group: 'xalan', module:'xalan'
    }
    compile ("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28",) {
        force = true
    }
    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2') {
        force = true
    }

    compile ('org.springframework:spring-beans:5.3.18') {
        force = true
    }

    compile ('org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.18') {
        force = true
    }
    
    compile ("org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0") {
        force = true
    }
    
    compile ('org.testng:testng:7.7.1') {
        force = true
    }

    compile ('io.vertx:vertx-web:4.4.0') {
        force = true
    }

    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.14.2') {
        force = true;
    }

    //AWS SDK 2.x for KMS access
    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.73')
    implementation('software.amazon.awssdk:kms') {
        exclude group: 'io.netty', module: '*'
    }

    
    // All the package definition that need to ignore.
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module : 'log4j'
        all*.exclude module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    }

    // Include non maven standard layout file into war
    testCompile (
            "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.27.0",
            "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.2",
            "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.2",
            'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19',
            'org.testcontainers:elasticsearch:1.15.1',
            "org.testcontainers:kafka:1.15.1",
            "org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.15.1",
            "org.awaitility:awaitility:3.0.0",
            "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.7.0"
    )
}

version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs.add("-XDignore.symbol.file")
    //options.compilerArgs.add("-Werror")
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
    options.deprecation = true
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

test {
    ignoreFailures = false
    reports.html.destination = file("$buildDir/test-reports")
    useJUnitPlatform()
    systemProperty "java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
}
```